How to go back one page and not straight to the main window? Flet
How can I make it so that from the “Buy an iPhone” window you can go back to the “Store” window?
For some reason, the “Buy iPhone” window goes straight to the “Home” window.
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Routes Example"
    page.window_width = 400
    page.window_height = 600

    def route_change(route):
        page.views.clear()
        page.views.append(
            ft.View(
                "/",
                [
                    ft.AppBar(title=ft.Text("Home"), bgcolor=ft.colors.SURFACE_VARIANT),
                    ft.ElevatedButton("Store", on_click=lambda _: page.go("/store")),
                ],
            )
        )
        if page.route == "/store":
            page.views.append(
                ft.View(
                    "/store",
                    [
                        ft.AppBar(title=ft.Text("Store"), bgcolor=ft.colors.SURFACE_VARIANT),
                        ft.ElevatedButton('Buy iPhone 15 Pro Max', on_click=lambda _: page.go('/iPhone 15 Pro Max')),

                    ],
                )
            )
        elif page.route == "/iPhone 15 Pro Max":
            page.views.append(
                ft.View(
                    "/iPhone 15 Pro Max",
                    controls=[
                        ft.AppBar(title=ft.Text("Buy iPhone"), bgcolor=ft.colors.SURFACE_VARIANT),
                        ft.Text('Test')
                    ]
                )
            )

        page.update()

    def view_pop(view):
        page.views.pop()
        top_view = page.views[-1]
        page.go(top_view.route)

    page.on_route_change = route_change
    page.on_view_pop = view_pop
    page.go(page.route)


ft.app(target=main)

I tried adding a button to go to the previous page myself, but there is no smooth transition.
When I press the back arrow, the animation of returning to the previous page starts on the wrong side
    elif page.route == "/iPhone 15 Pro Max":
        page.views.append(
            ft.View(
                "/iPhone 15 Pro Max",
                controls=[
                    ft.AppBar(title=ft.Text("Buy iPhone"), bgcolor=ft.colors.SURFACE_VARIANT,
                              leading=IconButton(icon=icons.ARROW_BACK_IOS,
                              on_click=lambda e: e.page.go('/store')), 
                              color='black'),

                    ft.Text('Test')
                ]
            )
        )

